# Using NOT IN in Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have two tables: GENRE and MOVIE. GENRE contains genre_code and genre_desc, while MOVIE has tile, genre_code, etc... I am trying to list all the genre_desc that are not are not associated with a title. I need to use NOT IN and avoid EXISTS.

I have tried -

```
SELECT GENRE.MOVIE_GENRE_DESC
FROM GENRE INNER JOIN MOVIE ON MOVIE.MOVIE_GENRE_CODE = MOVIE.GENRE_CODE
WHERE GENRE.MOVIE_GENRE_DESC Not In ([MOVIE].[GENRE_CODE]);
```

I just get a list of desc that have titles

Comment: Can you add sample data and expected result

Answer (score 1):

You can use this SQL with `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT Genre.genre_code, Genre.genre_desc
FROM Genre LEFT JOIN Movie ON Genre.genre_code = Movie.genre_code
WHERE Movie.id Is Null
```

or with `NOT IN`:

```
SELECT Genre.genre_code, Genre.genre_desc
FROM Genre 
WHERE Genre.genre_code not in (SELECT  Movie.genre_code FROM Movie )
```

First variant should work faster, `NOT IN` means not using indexes.